# How to list my website in a carousel of colleges in the Google search results?

Tags: google-search

If you search Google for colleges in St Louis, It shows list of colleges in a carousel. Why not showing mine?

[image]

I would like to know how to get my site to appear there.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing really that you can do other than running a website for a college in St Louis. The Google algorithms decide what sites rank as authoritative enough to be added to such a carousel. It is similar to the way that certain pages if deemed of high enough importance by Google can be shown as site links under your SERP page listing. This is an automated process and can't be tricked or manually applied.

Comment: I was digging around on some similar issues and found the same rules apply for the carousel as does to the for the knowledge graph card since they come from the same place. What could be missing is confirmation from a trusted source. For example, is there a Wikipedia page? How about a G+ page? The knowledge graph is fed directly from these sources and uses others are trusted. The knowledge graph requires that the entries can be confirmed from trusted source or by several less trusted sources.