# How to rank a book in the Google search book categories carousel?

Tags: google, google-search

I am an author of a farming book, I need to make my book to appear on the list of Google books as shown on the screenshot, I tried to use the http://schema.org/Book but i cant find anything that categorise books

[image]

Comment: I think the situation for books is similar to the situation for colleges that use the same carousel:  [How to list my website in a carousel of colleges in the Google search results?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/103482/how-to-list-my-website-in-a-carousel-of-colleges-in-the-google-search-results)    Google doesn't use schema from your website for this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For categories, you can use the following elements of **[Book](http://schema.org/Book)**:

- [**about**](http://schema.org/about) - The subject matter of the content.
- **[audience](http://schema.org/audience)** with property **[Audience](http://schema.org/Audience)** included. Please note that you can specify (see below More specific Types) this property as **[BusinessAudience](http://schema.org/BusinessAudience)** ++ **[EducationalAudience](http://schema.org/EducationalAudience)** ++ **[PeopleAudience](http://schema.org/PeopleAudience)**.
- **[genre](http://schema.org/genre)**